# ESP32 SPI issue (voltage levels)

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, spi, esp32

I have (technically had because it smoked while trying to resolve this issue) a PCB board with an [ESP32-WROOM-32](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08MQ647ZG) Dev Board plugged in. I had 4 external ADCs ([AD7680ARJZ-REEL7](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/AD7680ARJZ-REEL7/995494?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIIBEDsA2AHABjgJQFIC0BabAURIBkkQBdAXyA)). ADC 1 and 2 were on hspi and ADC 3 and 4 were on vspi (doesn't matter if hspi/vspi are switched). When I run the code with the ESP32 powered via my USB everything works fine. When I remove the power and rely solely on [L7805CV](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/L7805CV/585964) to supply 5V to the ESP's 5V pin ADC 3 and 4 stop working. I cut my USB cable off and touched the 5V on the USB directly to the 5V on the ESP32 and ADC pin 3 and 4 came alive. This makes me think the issue is with the supply voltage level.

As far as the hardware/wiring is concerned I had everything connected to the same ground. The L7805CV was nowhere near its current rating (was only slightly warm) but I did notice that the voltage on the L7805CV was only 4.97V while the voltage from the USB was 5.01V. Could this be causing the issue? I need to redesign my board and I'm trying to understand why I was seeing this issue.

Here is the code I used to read the 4 channels. I tried really long delays before and after setting the pins high and low and didn't make a difference. The highlights (I think) are the pins I used (SPI1_SCK = 14; SPI1_MISO = 12; ADC_CS_1 = 15; ADC_CS_2 = 21; SPI2_SCK = 18; SPI2_MISO = 19; ADC_CS_3 = 25; ADC_CS_4 = 26;)

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

const int SPI1_SCK = 14;
const int SPI1_MISO = 12;
const int ADC_CS_1 = 15;
const int ADC_CS_2 = 21;

const int SPI2_SCK = 18;
const int SPI2_MISO = 19;
const int ADC_CS_3 = 25;
const int ADC_CS_4 = 26;


unsigned char upper_byte;
unsigned char middle_byte;
unsigned char lower_byte;
unsigned int data;

//uninitalised pointers to SPI objects
SPIClass vspi(VSPI);
SPIClass hspi(HSPI);

// function declarations
int readData(SPIClass*, unsigned int);

// RS485 properties
HardwareSerial SerialPort(2); //UART2 on ESP32 module
const int RXpin = 16; //pin 16 recommended for RXD
const int TXpin = 17; //pin 17 recommended for TXD
const int slave_address = 102; //address must be hard coded (will not auto generate)

int regs[256]; //register array available to master
bool debug_read_esp = false;
bool debug_read_all = false; // only will read data coming to ESP32, good to determine if communication exists
bool debug_write = false;

const unsigned int numSamples = 40; // number of samples to take for each channel

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Set up the first SPI interface
  pinMode(ADC_CS_1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ADC_CS_1, HIGH);
  hspi.begin(SPI1_SCK, SPI1_MISO, -1, ADC_CS_1);

  pinMode(ADC_CS_2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ADC_CS_2, HIGH);
  hspi.begin(SPI1_SCK, SPI1_MISO, -1, ADC_CS_2);

  hspi.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV64); // ESP32 has SPI clock speed of 240MHz / 64 = 3.75MHz
  hspi.setDataMode(SPI_MODE2); // CPOL = 1, CPHA = 0 (clock is high in idle state, data sampled on rising edge)

  // Set up the second SPI interface
  pinMode(ADC_CS_3, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ADC_CS_3, HIGH);
  vspi.begin(SPI2_SCK, SPI2_MISO, -1, ADC_CS_3);

  pinMode(ADC_CS_4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ADC_CS_4, HIGH);
  vspi.begin(SPI2_SCK, SPI2_MISO, -1, ADC_CS_4);

  vspi.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV64); // ESP32 has SPI clock speed of 240MHz / 64 = 3.75MHz
  vspi.setDataMode(SPI_MODE2); // CPOL = 1, CPHA = 0 (clock is high in idle state, data sampled on rising edge)

  SerialPort.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXpin, TXpin); //UART: baud rate, serial config., rxd pin, txd pin

  delay(2000);
  SerialPort.flush();
  Serial.flush();

}

void loop() {
  
  unsigned int data_total_0 = 0;
  unsigned int data_total_1 = 0;
  unsigned int data_total_2 = 0;
  unsigned int data_total_3 = 0;

  //read the data into the registers
  for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++){
    data_total_0 += readData(&hspi, ADC_CS_1); // read data from channel 1
    data_total_1 += readData(&hspi, ADC_CS_2); // read data from channel 2
    data_total_2 += readData(&vspi, ADC_CS_3); // read data from channel 3
    data_total_3 += readData(&vspi, ADC_CS_4); // read data from channel 4
  }

  regs[0] = data_total_0 / numSamples;
  regs[1] = data_total_1 / numSamples;
  regs[2] = data_total_2 / numSamples;
  regs[3] = data_total_3 / numSamples;

  // check for a modbus command over the serial port
  if (SerialPort.available() > 7){
    decode();
  }
}

int readData(SPIClass* spi, unsigned int cs_pin) {
  //Format is 0000UUUU MMMMMMMM LLLL0000
  // returns 16 bit data
  digitalWrite(cs_pin, LOW);
  delay(1);
  upper_byte = spi->transfer(0x00);
  middle_byte = spi->transfer(0x00);
  lower_byte = spi->transfer(0x00);
  data = ((upper_byte << 12) | (middle_byte << 4) | (lower_byte >> 4));
  digitalWrite(cs_pin, HIGH);
  return data;
}
```

Edit: Adding schematic
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a schematic - a block diagram that shows how power is supplied would be adequate.

Comment: We don't know which board you have and how it is connected to anywhere and how it is designed. But the problem surely can't be a 40mV difference in a 5V input before it is converted to 3.3V to the ESP32. You need to show the schematics and how everything is connected. It is also not a great idea to directly put 5V from external source to 7805 output. Why there is a 7805 if the MCU uses 3.3V? What runs on 5V?

Comment: @Frog Just added schematic of power to ESP32.

I'm thinking of using a 9V LDO designated to supply power to ESP32.

Comment: @Justme - To externally power ESP32, 5V-12V needs to be applied

Comment: @jskooba The schematics are missing a major part regarding the possible problem of SPI ADCs not working with provided 5V.

Comment: @Justme okay added

Comment: @jskooba What is that, AD768? Something else? It is unreadable due to low resolution. Add the description in text.

Comment: @Justme https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/AD7680ARJZ-REEL7/995494?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIIBEDsA2AHABjgJQFIC0BabAURIBkkQBdAXyA

Comment: @jskooba Which ESP32 board that is, do you have the schematics? Do you have a level shifter between the ADC and ESP32 board? Please, write everything down like you were making instructions to your friend/colleague what to buy and how to connect them to replicate what you have done. And the problem could still be elsewhere than what you show, but we can only work with what you show.

Comment: @Justme okay I added some part numbers and links and gave a bigger screenshot of the WD. If anyone needs anything else to answer this question, please ask specifics.

Comment: 4.97V from a 7805 is nearly perfect, its tolerance is higher AFAIK. I'm sure there is no problem with the negligible difference to 5.00V. Your problem might be somewhere else, possibly including the direct connection of USB-5V to the output of the 7805.